# Java Regex to Strip Leading & Trailing Zeros with Spaces

Tags: java, regex

Strings of integers such as below, in Java how do I strip the leading and trailing zeros and make it look like:

- `0 0 1 2 3` becomes `1 2 3`
- `0 -2 4 0 0 0` becomes `-2 4`
- `0 3 0 -4 0 0` becomes `3 0 -4`
- `0 10 9 0 0 20 0` becomes `10 9 0 0 20`

Comment: [`/^[0\s]*|[0\s]*$/`](https://regex101.com/r/aS2yQ3/1)

Comment: how do you exactly use the code? It doesn't seem to work. Sorry I'm still a newbie in Java

Comment: this one kinda works. `str.replaceAll("^[0\\s]*[0\s]*$", "")` but the last case, where `0 10 9 0 0 20 0` becomes `10 9 0 0 2` instead of `10 9 0 0 20`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex does what you require, as far as I can see.

```
string pattern = "^[ 0]*|( |(?<!\d)0)*$";
str.replaceAll(pattern, "");
```

To explain: the expression is in two parts, seperated by the first `|`. The first part, `^[ 0]*`, simply looks for 0 or more spaces or zeros at the beginning of a line/string (`^` denotes start of line/string).

The second part, `( |(?<!\d)0)*$`, is a bit more complex, because of the special case where the last non-zero number in a line ends with the digit zero. This part looks for zero or more occurances of either space or `(?<!\d)0`, which means *zero not preceded by a digit*. The `?<!\d` part is called a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Lastly comes `$`, which denotes end of line/string.

Comment: thank you, this works. If you don't mind can you explain more about the pattern that you wrote

Comment: @ChristianSakai Yeah sorry, added explanation now :)

Comment: Good catch on the negative lookbehind that I missed on my quick comment.